# Best Third Party Payment System

Tags: online-payment

Me and a few developers are thinking about taking on a project that relies heavily on online transactions. Bare with me, please! I'm just looking for information/recommendations/advice.

The web app will be developed with mostly PHP, but again, open to suggestions

the application will have two different users, clients and owners. clients PAY the owners (Think of it as rent payment)

I'm looking for some expert advice as far as the best third party web software/api/library/processor/gateway (whatever is best) to use. I could use a crash course on what's best in the industry.

- I want clients to be able to pay owners via credit card/debit card OR store checking account information(routing #, account #)
- I want the payments to the owner to go directly to his/her bank account

Any information on the best way to go about this would be greatly appreciated!

This is planned to be a application in the USA

Comment: I've posted an answer below; but you might want to state what country you're located in, what country the owner is located in, or any other constraints (ie, is it a "tricky" industry type that can sometimes have problems getting a merchant account?) That info may help others provide other, better options.

Answer (score 1):

[CDG Commerce](http://www.cdgcommerce.com/) offers reliable (IMHO) payment options - and payments are batch-processed nightly to go into the account holder's bank account. (As far as I know, accepting payments online through your own site very often requires a merchant account - unless you're going to use something like Paypal. CDG will quickly and easily walk you through setting up a merchant account, if your app owner doesn't already have one.) CDG Commerce offers Quantum Gateway as the payment processor. There is a monthly charge, and they do have a restriction on what types of businesses can use their service (the same types of restrictions that most payment processors have, with a little more latitude.) You can very easily add the payment widgets to whatever app you're building, or they have an API that lets you customize things to more seamlessly match your app.

EDIT: I have used 2checkout, Sagepay, Worldpay...and just wasn't all that thrilled with them. I liked using CDG Commerce much much better.

Comment: Good to go over all the requirements listed in the question if possible.